# SQL inner joins with table alias' - Can I optimize this query?

Tags: sql, query-optimization, inner-join

I was looking at the SSMS Tools Execution Plan Analyzer and it said to try breaking it up into smaller chunks. Is the following query the best way I can do "this"? Any help is much appreciated!

```
SELECT t1.ID,
t1.col2,
t1.col3,
t1.col4,
t2.ID AS table2ID,
t2.col2,
t1.col5,
t1.col6,
t2.StatusID as table2StatusID
CASE WHEN LEN(t2.ErrorMessage) > 0 THEN t3.StatusName + ' ' + t2.ErrorMessage 
             ELSE t3.StatusName
     END AS SomeStatus,
     t3.StatusTypeID AS StatusTypeID
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.StatusID = t3.StatusID`
```

Comment: What exactly is the "it" you are trying to break into smaller chunks?

Comment: The "it" is the whole query I suppose. I'm new to SQL and the Execution Plan Analyzer said to break this query into smaller chunks and maybe use a temp table.

Comment: I'm trying to optimize the speed at which the query runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your case when with an ISNULL() which might reduce the per row processing cost.

```
t3.StatusName + ISNULL(' ' + t2.ErrorMessage, '') as SomeStatus
```

Without knowing a great deal about your schema setup it's difficult to tell where optimizations can be made. What might be intuitive optimizations might go against business logic and be useless. The alternative is true, there could be some short cuts  to getting the data that isn't obvious without knowing the business logic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just started out at a company and am hesitant to reveal anything really so I try to keep things very specific but I do agree with you that knowing more would help haha.

Answer (score 0):

The query seems pretty straight forward.  The one suggestion I would have is if you can change t2.ErrorMessage to be null if it doesn't exist then you can use the IsNull vs CASE which can be more efficient.